# Should I Use std::begin with an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

As a simple example, take a look at this code (or imagine array-specific code rather than templates and other general coding techniques):

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,7,8,9,55};
vector<int> v(a, end(a));
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

I was wondering if there is a coding reason to use `std::begin` here or in perhaps different settings (other than style/consistency/compatibility with future code changes/etc.). Would there be a place where it is actually required?

What are your thoughts on using `begin(a)` there in terms of coding practices? To me, it's a touchy topic, because you risk the appearance of not knowing about the fundamental operation of arrays and pointers in C++ if you mindlessly call `std::begin`. Realistically, I may never need the ability to change containers. I mean, come on. If you actually changed the container, you'd get a compiler bug and fix it in 3 seconds.

You've heard of "premature optimization". I'd call using `std::begin` here "premature generality".

Comment: The train of thought that you can break code by changing something and fix it in a few seconds is going to lead you to a big problem. Not all code is 10 lines.

Comment: @chris You are overgeneralizing my stance. In this particular case, even if the files were 10,000 lines of code, the compiler would highlight each problematic area very specifically. You'd then change it in a matter of minutes. And this would only happen in the rare and understandably time-consuming case of changing an entire container for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are your thoughts on using begin(a) there in terms of coding
>   practices?

Use it.

Assuming you're talking about using `begin` as opposed to indexing an array (eg `arry[0]`), your presumption that changing a container and fixing the resulting compiler errors will be simple is *unrealistic*.

Imagine a codebase consisting of 1,000,000 lines of code in dozens of different modules spread out all over the place.  You might be trying to access this collection from anywhere, and from places you have long since forgotten about.  It could take hours or days to fix all the compiler errors.  The example is not contrived.  The codebase I work on is several million lines of code -- some of which I forgot about years ago.

Comment: But how often do you actually change widely-used containers in your 1 million lines of code? I like to think that the times people actually make such changes is contrived - not the fact that code can get big and involved.

Comment: @user904963:  Hopefully very rarely.  It does happen however, and when it does the last thing you need is to *also* have to fix all those c-style index accessors to something that works with the new container.

Comment: I haven't entirely stopped using raw arrays, but i don't let them roam widely. In a million-line project, at least the important data should be properly wrapped in classes.

Answer (score 4):

As a practice, using `begin` in this context really doesn't hold any of the downsides you think it holds. On the contrary, not using it seems inconsistent and a pointless complication for the sake of showing off that you understand an aspect of how C++ works. It will cause the next guy to look at this code to look twice to understand why you didn't use `begin` and `end` symmetrically, wasting time.

More concretely, using `begin` here allows you to change out the type of `a` without breaking any code.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use it when writing templates.
In regular code you're right, it's not needed.

If you write templates that work with containers then you don't know if it's a regular array or vector or something else. So using `x.begin()` will not work for arrays and any thing that works with arrays will not work with STL containers. So you use begin to bridge the gap and ignore the differences so that the template just works with  both arrays and STL containers.

Comment: I'm liking this comment the most so far, though I will consider the other side fairly and let things settle. I admit that using `std::begin` in general code is a good idea since `std::begin` is general. But I also think that array-specific code should be customized with FUNDAMENTAL KNOWLEDGE OF C++ AND HOW IT WORKS.

Comment: @user904963:  Re:  " FUNDAMENTAL KNOWLEDGE OF C++ AND HOW IT WORKS"  Why is this needed?

Comment: @JohnDibling Precision can convey information. A viewer of that code automatically can crack a guess that `a` is an array without even seeing its declaration. On the other hand, using `a.begin()` and so forth let's them crack a guess that it's some sort of container. Using `begin(a)` means you have to look elsewhere for more hints. There is obviously a time when too much information "overloads the screen" (e.g. using `vector<vector<vector<int>>>::difference_type` instead of `auto`), but in this situation, the more informative approach actually reduces the screen usage.

Comment: Seeing code like `ary[i]` tells you almost nothing about the actual type of `ary`.  It could be a C-style array, it could be a `vector`, it could be a `map`, it could be some custom class with an `operator[]` overload...  Further, well-designed code means that typically you don't need to know or care what exactly `ary` is -- only what it does and how to use it.  See:  templates.

Comment: @JohnDibling But by your own requirements, doesn't knowing what "it does" and "how to use it" imply you should know that `ary` is an array rather than a more feature-filled and safe alternative? I just had a thought, though. It seems this discussion is a bit useless. My book hasn't gotten to `std::array`, but when it does, I imagine I will never use an array again except for working with old code. With that container, we'd have to use `std::begin` or `array::begin` for it even to compile.

Comment: @user904963:  Perhaps to an extent at times.  Most of the time the general sense that "this is a bag of Widgets," is all you need -- and all you should need.  To convey the idea that "this is a bag of Widgets," as opposed to say, "This is a sprocket," is the job of the name you choose for the variable -- not the syntax you use to utilize the variable.

Comment: @user904963:  Let me turn the tables on you for a moment.  Why would you need to know that `ary` is a `vector` of `Widget`s as opposed to a C-style array?

Comment: @Sorin:  You're correct that using `x.begin()` won't work with C-style arrays, but `begin(x)` will -- and that's what being discussed here.

Comment: @JohnDibling The only difference I can think of is a `vector` guarantees its entries are value-initialized whereas if we have a c-style array, we have to make sure not to use `a[i]` unless we put something in there first. But other than these situations, I see your point. Literally every STL function that deals with iterators and what not work with arrays in the same way.

Comment: @user904963:  Re: "we have to make sure not to use a[i]"  That's true, certianly, but -- and if I blow your mind here I apologize -- that's not unique to `a[i]`.  The same is true of every datatype in C++:  before you can access it, it has to be initialized.  It just so happens that it's impossible to add a (legally accessible) element to a `vector` without it having been initialized, as you observed.  I guess my point here is that you still don't need to know that `ary` is an array.  All you need to know is basic C++, and you need that for everything.

Comment: @JohnDibling Sure, but you have to admit this one important distinction: Every STL algorithm works pretty much by default with `begin` and `end` for STL containers (i.e. no crashes). But for an array, calling the same algorithm with `begin` and `end` could result in a crash. The only way to avoid this is to be intimate with the fact you are dealing with an array. If for some reason you only need parts of the array in a fashion similar to a vector and for some reason justify an array, you'd have to replace `end` with `next(begin(arr), numUsed)`

Comment: @user904963:  I must not completely understand what you're trying to say.  Why can't you just `foo( begin(ary), end(ary))` regardless of `ary` being a `vector` or an array?  Did I misunderstand you completely?

Comment: @JohnDibling Take a simple `int a[5]` and `vector<int> v`. If I will do something that grows the end like a vector, and for some reason wish to use some STL algorithm function `f` on the valid range, I cannot use: `f(begin(a), end(a))` like I can with `v`. It could crash. The only ways around this are to value-initialize the array or keep track of numUsed. The first way would also result in needless looping, so the second way would be preferred. The first way could also result in a "wrong answer".

Comment: @user904963:  Ah, I think I got you now.  Yes, you're right.  If `f` *accesses* elements in `v` then `v` has to be initialized.  If `v` is going to do the initialization then that's fine, but I don't think that's what you're talking about.